# Ubuntu 17.04 laptop wakes up by itself after a few hours

Tags: suspend, thinkpad, 17.04

After closing the lid the computer wakes up by itself after a few hours. I found it in my bag burning hot...

This is an X1 Carbon Thinkpad. It hasn't happened before the upgrade to 17.04.

Comment: I doubt Ubuntu has woken up. I think the lid switch is very critical or, if at all present, the lid's latch was not closed properly. Perhaps you should consider hibernation instead of suspending.

Comment: I have been carrying this laptop around in the same backpack since 2013, and this has never happened before 17.04. Now it has happened twice in a few days. So I don't think that it was because of the lid opening.

Comment: Also, when I took the computer out of the bag the lid was definitely closed, but the computer was awake. This shouldn't happen under any circumstance.

Comment: Umm.. I suppose you checked the lid settings after the upgrade to 17.04 ? With a closed lid its difficult to test waking up the laptop. I do see a few postings on the internet regarding suspend issues with 17.04. Perhaps you have found a bug.

Comment: The lid settings are suspend when closed, and indeed it does suspend when I close it - but then wakes up later. I can tell if the laptop is suspended when it is closed by a light on the outside of the lid.

Comment: I see what you mean, it will be difficult to find find out what makes it wake up...  :(